# How can i convert a datatable into an object in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have two DataTables (dt1 and dt2) and i want to convert them into an object of a class (data1 and data2), so i can use the compareTo method an put it into a binding List.

```
Public Class MainForm

    Public dt1, dt2 As DataTable
    Public data1, data2 As ISAACService
    Private Sub btnDatei1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDatei1.Click
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            If File.Exists(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) Then
                dt1 = FileGenerator.ReadFromProtectedFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
                dgv1.DataSource = dt1
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnVergleich_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVergleich.Click
        CompareDataTables()
    End Sub




    Private Sub btnDatei2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDatei2.Click
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            dt2 = FileGenerator.ReadFromProtectedFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            dgv2.DataSource = dt2
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CompareDataTables()
        data1 = CType(dt1, ISAACService)
        For i = 0 To dt1.Rows.Count - 1
            If i < dt2.Rows.Count Then
                Dim row1 = dt1.Rows(i)
                Dim row2 = dt2.Rows(i)
                data1.CompareTo(data2)
                '
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

The compareTo method:

```
Public Function CompareTo(other As ISAACService) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of ISAACService).CompareTo

        If other.GetType() Is GetType(ISAACService) Then
            other = CType(other, ISAACService)

            If Me.UANR > other.UANR Then
                Return 1
            ElseIf Me.UANR < other.UANR Then
                Return -1
            Else
                Return 0
            End If
        End If
        Return 0

    End Function
```

The class for the object:

```
Public MustInherit Class ISAACServiceBase


    ReadOnly Property KostenArt As String
    ReadOnly Property UANR As String
    ReadOnly Property Überbegriff As String
    ReadOnly Property Benennung As String
    ReadOnly Property Anzahl As Double
    ReadOnly Property Einheit As String
    ReadOnly Property Einzelkosten As Double
    ReadOnly Property Gesamtmenge As Integer
    ReadOnly Property Z As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(kArt As String, uNR As String, üBegriff As String, bnung As String, anzl As Double, enht As String, eKosten As Double, gMenge As Integer, zz As String)
        KostenArt = kArt
        UANR = uNR
        Überbegriff = üBegriff
        Benennung = bnung
        Anzahl = anzl
        Einheit = enht
        Einzelkosten = eKosten
        Gesamtmenge = gMenge
        Z = zz
    End Sub

End Class
```

Please let me know if you need any further information. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: You can't magically turn an object of one type into an object of another type. In order for `CType` to work, there would have to be code inside the `DataTable` class to create an object of type `ISAACService`, populate it with the data from the `DataTable` and then return it. There is no such code so you have to write your own method that takes a `DataTable` as input, creates and populates an `ISAACService` and then returns it.

Comment: Also, given that a `DataTable` generally contains multiple `DataRows`, are you sure that it makes sense to generate a single `ISAACService` object? Should it actually be an array or collection of such objects; one per row?

Comment: @jmcilhinney No it doesnt make sense, you're right, Can you tell me how I can populate ISAAC Service with data from DataTable? Should I use the constructor for it?

Comment: Create an instance and set the properties, like you would for any other object. You can add a constructor with parameters if you want but you know what that type is and does so you need to decide whether doing so makes sense.

Comment: @jmcilhinney but i need to make an instace for every row, right? When I do it with an for each loop, how can i manage it that every instance has a different name?

Comment: What name? Each instance has property values. If you need to be able to identify an instance by a name then you need a property to store it and it has to come from somewhere. That's for you to decide. Do you actually need a name at all? You've said nothing in your question about names so this is out of scope. Maybe you should delete this question and post a new one that actually explains what you really need, now that you know what was wrong with your original approach.

Comment: @jmcilhinney "create an instance and set the properties". If i make an instance of an object i need a name for it. "Does it make sense to genereate a single object?" No, so i need to make an object for every row, that means if i have 10 rows i need 10 names for these objects. Am I completely out of line? I will try to make it clearer what i want to know and delete this question as far as i have it figured out. Thank you for your help

Comment: "If i make an instance of an object i need a name for it". No, you don't. I suspect that what you are calling a "name" is actually a variable that you need to assign the object to. Yes, you need to do that, but that's not the name of the object. You can assign the same object to multiple variables and multiple objects to the same variable at different times. I think that you are lacking an understanding of some of the fundamentals of programming.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Public obj1 As New ISAACService. "obj1" is what i mean as name. But i cant have multiple objectes with the same name.

Comment: The instance of your class will be identified by the index in the collection (array, list, whatever) that you add it to in the loop. You don't have a separate variable name for each instance. You just reused (overwrite) the variable on each iteration. Then add the new instance to the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function to do the conversions. Of course, I have no idea if the `DataTable` fields line up with the Properties of the class. You may have to change the field indexes for the `row`.

```
Private Function CovertDataTableToListOfISAACService(dt As DataTable) As List(Of ISAACService)
    Dim lst As New List(Of ISAACService)
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim ISAAC As New ISAACService(row(0).ToString, row(1).ToString, row(2).ToString, row(3).ToString, CDbl(row(4)), row(5).ToString, CDbl(row(6)), CInt(row(7)), row(8).ToString)
        lst.Add(ISAAC)
    Next
    Return lst
End Function
```

Your compare function starts out validating the type of `other`.
other is already guaranteed to be `ISAACService` because that is the type of the parameter. I am not sure what you are comparing other to but that is not what the question asks.

Comment: I just validated it with "other" because i know it like that from java. I want to compare if the datatables are the same, if something was added/deleted/modified  I put everything in an ultragrid and highlight the changes. Thank you for your answer, you helped me a lot.